# alternative to XtraTreeList for vb6

Tags: vb6, treeview, xtratreelist, treelist

I'm looking for a advanced treeview component for vb6.
Is there any better alternative to [XtraTreeList](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2434) of [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com)?

Thanks

Comment: Better is subjective. For you, better hmeans what? How does that tree and the native Win32 Treeview not do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the built-in Treeview control quite limited, we use the VSFlexGrid from [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/VSFlexGridPro/).  It's fairly easy to create a treeview using their control.

[image]

Comment: +1 Haven't used its tree-abilities, but the VSFlexGrid is a good component in general.  We long ago standardized on that for our VB6 software.